# Bash script — wget doesn't use a variable with "{}" correctly

Tags: bash, variables, unix, wget

I'm using a script that downloads images. I am having issues while running the `wget` command with a variable that contains "{" and "}" characters. It transforms into "%7B" and "%7D".

Here is part of the script

```
wget -nd -H -p -A jpg,jpeg,png,gif -e robots=off "$url"
```

The `"$url"` contains something like `"http://webpage.com/di1/dir2/{1..26}.jpg"`.

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Sooooo .. is there a way to fix it , becouse the command runs OK if I don't run it inside a script

Comment: use `for url in http://webpage.com/di1/dir2/{1..26}.jpg; do wget ... done` .... you can even add an `&` to download in parallel

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @Quarks: Why does `$url` contain `{1..26}`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I get the Directory from a Web page so I get " http://webpage.com/di1/dir2/" By that I was use to do wget with
 http://webpage.com/di1/dir2/{1..50}.jpg so it repeats 50 times getting 50 images. But in a script using "{,}" values not working so I made a Loop instead. -.-

Comment: [Brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) doesn't occur inside quoted strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a Loop

```
for i in {1..50}
do
  wget "$url$i.jpg"
done
```